# OFFSET Function in Excel just for non-duplicated data

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate

I want to use OFFSET function to triple the data in a column. But I have some duplicated data (sometimes more than 2 repetition) that I want to just triple one of them not both and keep the other one. Here is my data and function:

```
 =OFFSET($A$2,INT((ROWS($A$2:A2)-1)/3),0)
               A
 2      5YJSA3H17EFP49729
 3      5YJSA3H17EFP41128
 4      5YJSA3H17EFP30954
 5      5YJSA3H17EFP30954
 6      5YJSA3H17EFP30212
 7      5YJSA3H17EFP30050
```

In this example 5YJSA3H17EFP30954 is duplicated but I just want to perform OFFSET on one of them and keep the other one, so I want to have 4 repetitions of that.

Comment: Neither of `OFFSET()` or `INT()` has any "magic" extras that skips duplicates in your source data. 
You better explain what you are trying to achieve in more detail.

Comment: @Hannu I just want to have three repetitions for each data and if there are duplicate or more than that, just do this function for one of them and keep the other replicates without any changes.

Comment: You have a missing `0` at the end of `OFFSET(...` -> it should be `...),0)`

Comment: So do you want to filter out duplicates and then work with those uniques?

Comment: As I understand it; THREE repetitions of ONE original, FOUR repetitions for duplicate originals.

Comment: @Hannu Exactly, THREE repetitions of ONE original, FOUR repetitions for duplicate originals and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter these into B2 and C2

```
B2
=IFERROR(IF(AND(A2=A1;B1=3);1;IF(AND(A2=A1;B1<3);0;3));3)

C2
=IFERROR(OFFSET(B2;-1;0)+OFFSET(C2;-1;0);0)
```

and then fill the B and C columns with those, you will get a tables for:
B) how many times each item (on the same row) should repeat in column
C) which A1-offset-row to pick the repeated value from.

Now, I don't think this is possible to accomplish with formulas.

VBA needs to be used; below you find a "sub" (with the logic/formulas picked from above) that will create the requested table, given your table starting in A1

```
Sub createDupeTable()

  r = 1: c = 1   ' Assumption: for accessing A1 with Cells(r,c)
  br = 1: bc = c + 1 ' where to start inserting copies, Cells(br,bc)

 ' value in "B1" (above) always 3
  pz = 3

  Do While Cells(r, c).Value <> ""
    a1 = Cells(r, c).Value
    a2 = Cells(r + 1, c).Value
    b1 = pz
    If a2 = a1 And b1 = 3 Then
      Z = 1
    Else
      If a2 = a1 And b1 < 3 Then
        Z = 0
      Else
        Z = 3
      End If
    End If

    pz = Z
    Do While Z > 0
      Cells(br, bc).Value = Cells(r, c).Value ' copy one value from the list
      Z = Z - 1
      br = br + 1
    Loop

    r = r + 1
  Loop
End Sub
```

The result:

```
     A                   B
1   5YJSA3H17EFP49729   5YJSA3H17EFP49729
2   5YJSA3H17EFP41128   5YJSA3H17EFP49729
3   5YJSA3H17EFP30954   5YJSA3H17EFP49729
4   5YJSA3H17EFP30954   5YJSA3H17EFP41128
5   5YJSA3H17EFP30212   5YJSA3H17EFP41128
6   5YJSA3H17EFP30050   5YJSA3H17EFP41128
7                       5YJSA3H17EFP30954
8                       5YJSA3H17EFP30954
9                       5YJSA3H17EFP30954
10                      5YJSA3H17EFP30954
11                      5YJSA3H17EFP30212
12                      5YJSA3H17EFP30212
13                      5YJSA3H17EFP30212
14                      5YJSA3H17EFP30050
15                      5YJSA3H17EFP30050
16                      5YJSA3H17EFP30050
```

Comment: Thank Hannu, but it gives me error..I'll work on that.

Comment: Had the opportunity to verify the code, now it works.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just, there is one problem..For 3 repetitions, it creates 4 data instead of 5...

Comment: Hmm... I wish I had means to test, try change `Z=0` into `Z=1` (one place), I think that should do it. That will make it do 3 'data' for the first occurance in the original, then 1 extra 'data' per *ALL* repeated occurances (with the zero [as above] it does only one extra 'data' for *any* number of repeats).

Comment: Great ;-)  - I believe a few lines above may be removed still retaining the new functionality; but I think I'll leave it as is.